# Encrypting and decrypting a zip file in Android?

Tags: java, android, zip, encryption

I am using this code: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/crypto/encrypt-decrypt-file-stream-with-des for encrypting my zip files used in android app .It is working really fine with the zip files when I tried it using java code ,But when I tried same methods in Android app - It decrypts the file but file I get is corrupted and unable to open it.

Log:

```
         04-19 10:58:25.711: W/System.err(6752): net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: zip headers not found. probably not a zip file
         04-19 10:58:25.721: W/System.err(6752):    at net.lingala.zip4j.core.HeaderReader.readEndOfCentralDirectoryRecord(HeaderReader.java:122)
```

And when I  try to open the same file on Windows with winzip it displays:

```
   Does not appear to be a valid archive file.
```

Update::

```
public class EncryptDecryptFileStreamWithDES {

private static Cipher ecipher;
private static Cipher dcipher;

// 8-byte initialization vector
private static byte[] iv = {
    (byte)0xB2, (byte)0x12, (byte)0xD5, (byte)0xB2,
    (byte)0x44, (byte)0x21, (byte)0xC3, (byte)0xC3
};

public static void call() {

    try {

        SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    //    encrypt(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\zipped\\4.zip"), new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\zipped\\4.dat"));
      //  decrypt(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\zipped\\4.dat"), new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\zipped\\4new.zip"));

    //}
    //catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //System.out.println("File Not Found:" + e.getMessage());
        //return;
    }
    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Alogorithm Parameter:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("No Such Algorithm:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("No Such Padding:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Key:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

}

public static void encrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {

    try {

        call();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        // bytes at this stream are first encoded
        os = new CipherOutputStream(os, ecipher);

        // read in the clear text and write to out to encrypt
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            os.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }

        // close all streams
        os.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public static void decrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {

    try {

        call();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        // bytes read from stream will be decrypted
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, dcipher);

        // read in the decrypted bytes and write the clear text to out
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = cis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            os.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }

        // close all streams
        cis.close();
        is.close();
        os.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

This is the Class which I am using:

Comment: how would we know what you are doing wrong if we cant see your code?

Comment: Compare the decrypted file size with the original file's. And do show your actual code. BTW, you probably shouldn't be using DES, it's fairly easy to brute-force nowadays.

Comment: The Size is same as to orignal zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use different keys to encrypt and decrypt the file:

1) You call `encrypt(..)` from somewhere outside the `EncryptDecryptFileStreamWithDES`, which in its turn calls your `call()` method, which initializes new key:

```
SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
```

2) Then you call `decrypt(..)`, which calls your `call()` method again and you get new `SecretKey`.

There is no such a problem in the example you used, there is an opposite order of these methods invocations.
To extend this example you need to hold the key between invocation of `encrypt(..)` and `decrypt(..)` and then initialize `SecretKeySpec` with the key stored:

```
byte[] keyBytes = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").getEncoded();

...

SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
```

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UsingCipherInputStream.htm) is a little bit more real-life example.

P.S. As it was mentioned, using `DES` algorithm is not the best idea, use `AES` instead.

Comment: Got Ur Point Can u Help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228980/encryption-and-decryption-of-a-zip-file-in-android